# IOException: Resetting to invalid mark in Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-gallery, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to upload an image from phone's gallery to a server. I tried Glide and Picasso library. But it is not showing the selected image in ImageView. So, I'm scaling down the image as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html). This method works fine with most of the phones. But I found that it is not working in OnePlus 5 or 5T (Android - Oxygen: 8.0.0). It is showing following exception. The same code works fine if I take a picture using the camera and upload it.

```
04-14 16:13:43.207 26947-27295/me.example.app W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:450)
    at me.example.app .Fragment.ImageUploadFragment.decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(ImageUploadFragment.java:172)
    at me.example.app .Fragment.ImageUploadFragment$GetResizedBitmapTask.doInBackground(ImageUploadFragment.java:124)
    at me.example.app .Fragment.ImageUploadFragment$GetResizedBitmapTask.doInBackground(ImageUploadFragment.java:105)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
```

**Code for reference:**
**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLARY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
       imageUploadFragment.resizeImage(data.getData(), IMAGE_MAX_DIMENSION);
  }

}

....

@Override
public void onBitmapResized(Bitmap resizedBitmap, int maxDimension) {

    if (resizedBitmap != null){          
        Log.i("image", "resized");
        imgSelected.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }

}
```

**ImageUploadFragment:**

```
public void resizeImage(Uri uri, int maxDimension){
    GetResizedBitmapTask getResizedBitmapTask = new GetResizedBitmapTask(maxDimension);
    getResizedBitmapTask.execute(uri);
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class GetResizedBitmapTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap> {

    private int mMaxDimension;

    GetResizedBitmapTask(int maxDimension) {
        this.mMaxDimension = maxDimension;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... uris) {

        Uri uri = uris[0];

        if (uri != null){

            Bitmap bitmap;

            try {
                bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(uri, mMaxDimension, mMaxDimension);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //****this exception I'm getting****
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

        if (mImageTaskCallbacks != null)
        mImageTaskCallbacks.onBitmapResized(bitmap, mMaxDimension);
    }
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(Uri imageUri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException{

    //gets bytes of data from image file
    InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

    if (inputStream == null){
        return null;
    }

    InputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

    //marks the current position in the InputStream based on the number of bytes remaining to read in the buffer
    bufferedInputStream.mark(bufferedInputStream.available());

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    //decoder will return null (no bitmap)
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, options);

    bufferedInputStream.reset();

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, options);

    //****this line of code causing the exception****
    bufferedInputStream.reset();

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, options);

}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){

    int inSampleSize = 1;

    final int width = options.outWidth;
    final int height = options.outHeight;

    if (width > reqWidth || height > reqHeight){
        final int halfWidth = width/2;
        final int halfHeight = height/2;

        while ((halfWidth/inSampleSize) > reqWidth && (halfHeight/inSampleSize) > reqHeight){
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Thank you in advance.